# Отправка текста из своего приложения в мессенджер

Tags: java, android, sms, android-studio

Есть TextView с определенным текстом внутри. Каким способом отправить этот текст в мессенджер (WhatsApp, Viber, стоковое СМС приложение)? Может, создать кнопку "Share", но я с этим не знаком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашли уже ответ? Вот если что.

```
private void openApp(String packageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.setPackage(packageName); //имя пакета приложения
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text); // текст отправки
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
}
```